# Finding all the files under a directory in turtle that match a pattern

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I'd like to use the [find](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.3.6/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:find) function from the turtle package such that it matches any file path (in order to get an equivalent behavior to `find .` in bash). However I cannot find a wildcard [pattern](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.3.6/docs/Turtle-Pattern.html#t:Pattern) that I can use with this function.

```
find :: Pattern a -> FilePath -> Shell FilePath
```

I guess I could construct a pattern that matches any character zero or more times, but I'd like to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`lsif`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.3.6/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:lsif) sounds more like what you want. The documentation contains an example how to print the complete tree:

> ```
> lstree = lsif (\_ -> return True)
> ```

So in your case, you would use

```
lstree "."
```

Note that the output between `find` and `lstree "."` differs slightly: the original path isn't duplicated in the latter.